# Angularjs - diretiva ng-show não está funcionando em aplicação java

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Pessoal estou tentando usar a diretiva `ng-show` do AngularJS em uma aplicação Spring MVC, mas não estou conseguindo, simplesmente ela não está funcionando. Obs.: Eu estou usando o AngularJS normalmente, as outras diretivas, mas `ng-show` e `ng-hide` não funcionam, mesmo eu pegando o exemplo do site do AngularJS não funciona. Segue o que eu estou fazendo logo abaixo:

Na minha página *.jsp* eu faço isso:

```
<div ng-show="mostra">
  <span>conteúdo para mostra ou esconder</span>
</div>
```

No meu *controller* eu defino o valor de `mostra` da seguinte maneira:

```
$scope.mostra = false;
```

Dessa maneira pela documentação do AngularJS não era para mostra o conteúdo dentro da `div`. Eu já importei os arquivos do AngularJS, inclusive, como eu disse anteriormente, eu estou usando o *Framework* para fazer o controle das minhas páginas, para exibir conteúdo nas minhas tabelas e etc. Então, não sei o porque dessa diretiva não está funcionando. Alguém pode me ajudar? Eu uso essas diretivas no Sublime Text e tudo funciona normalmente, nesse projeto estou usando o Eclipse.

Segue abaixo o código da página:

```
<div align="center">
<form action="{{action}}" id="formCaixaDizimo"
    target="_blank">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>{{legenda}}</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="10" style="background: aqua;">Selecione o nome da Igreja</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <label for="igreja">Igreja: </label> 
                    <select ng-change="selectTodasIgrejas()" ng-model="igreja" ng-options="igreja.igreja.nome for igreja in todasIgrejas">
                        <option value="">..Selecione...</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <div ng-show="mostra">
                <tr>
                <td colspan="10" style="background: aqua;">Selecione o nome do
                    Membro</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="membro">Membro: </label> 
                        <select required="true" ng-change="selectMembroPorIgreja()" ng-model="membro" ng-options="membro.membro.nome for membro in membroPorIgreja">
                            <option value="">..Selecione...</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="habilita">Pesquisar</button>
    <button type="reset"class="btn btn-inverse">Limpar</button>
</form>
```

Segue o código do *controller*:

```
app.controller('geraCartaoMembro', function($scope, $http, MembroService, $log, $location) {

$scope.habilita = true;

$scope.mostra = false;

$http.get('ListaTodasIgrejas').success(function(data) {
    $scope.todasIgrejas = data;
});

var idigreja = null;

var idmembro = null;

function listaMembro(idigreja) {

    $scope.membroPorIgreja = MembroService.listaMembroParaGerarCartao({url: 'ListaMembroGeraCartao', idigreja: idigreja}, function() {

    }, function(error) {
        $scope.erroMembro = "Houver um problema na requisição do serviço. Tente mais tarde ou entre em contato com o administrador da aplicação";
    });
};


if($location.url() == '/pesquisaCartaoMembroPorNome') {

    $log.log($scope.mostra);

    $scope.legenda = "Gerar cartão de membro de acordo com o nome da igreja e do membro";

    $scope.selectTodasIgrejas = function() {
        $scope.habilita = true;

        idigreja = $scope.igreja.igreja.idigreja;

        $log.log("idigreja: " + idigreja);

        listaMembro(idigreja);

    };

    $scope.selectMembroPorIgreja = function() {
        idmembro = $scope.membro.membro.idmembro;

        $scope.action = "cartaoMembroPorNome/" + idigreja + "/" + idmembro;

        $scope.habilita = false;
    };

} else if ($location.url() == '/pesquisaCartaoMembro') {
    $log.log($scope.mostra);

    $scope.legenda = "Gerar cartão de membro de acordo com a igreja - gera de todos os membros da igreja selecionada";

    $scope.selectTodasIgrejas = function() {

        $scope.habilita = false;

        idigreja = $scope.igreja.igreja.idigreja;

        $scope.action = "cartaoMembro/" + idigreja;
    };
}
```

});

No `$routeProvider` é que eu determino o *controller* da página, segue como eu faço:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/pesquisaCartaoMembroPorNome',{
       templateUrl: '/igreja/views/dizimo/RelatorioDizimo.jsp',
       controller: 'geraCartaoMembro'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/pesquisaCartaoMembro',{
       templateUrl: '/igreja/views/dizimo/RelatorioDizimo.jsp',
       controller: 'geraCartaoMembro'
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}
```

Comment: Não vejo outra coisa que possa estar causando este problema além do fato de você estar colocando uma `div` dentro de um `table`. A `div` só pode ficar dentro do `td`. Ou seja, é permitido `table > tbody > tr > td`, mas não `table > tbody > div`.

Comment: Mesmo eu colocando dentro da <tr> ou da <td> ou até mesmo usando dentro da <div> só que fora da tabela, mesmo assim não está funcionando, se eu pegar o exemplo da página do angularjs também não funciona. O que será que está acontecendo? Tendo em vista que as outras funções do angular estão funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Não sei. Tente minimizar seu código ao máximo, para termos um erro minimamente reprodutível e reduzir os possíveis problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, você chegou a colocar a `ng-controller` na *view*?

Tente utilizar o `ng-if` ao invés do `ng-show`.

Segue, um exemplo para melhor entendimento:

```js
function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.mostra = false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app ng-controller="MainController">
  <div ng-if="mostra">
    <label for="membro">Membro: </label> 
    <select required="true" ng-change="selectMembroPorIgreja()" ng-model="membro" ng-options="membro.membro.nome for membro in membroPorIgreja">
      <option value="">..Selecione...</option>
    </select>   
  </div>
</body>
```